# Tensile force on a metal cable

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, string, stress-strain

Suppose you have a steel cable that has a certain elastic limit. Then I decide to use this cable to support an elevator of a certain mass $m$. Certainly the cable goes under some stress due to the weight of the elevator. However, if I start to accelerate the elevator upwards, will the tension in the cable increase since the force I am applying is in the opposite direction with respect to the weight of the elevator.

In other words, will the tension be equal to $\text{Weight} - \text{Acceleration} \times  \text{Mass}$?

Comment: These kinds of problems are easily solved once you have drawn up a Free Body Diagram (Google it if you don't know what it is).

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer mentions, by a free body diagram we get:
$$T=m(a+g)$$
So yes, this would imply that "the higher the acceleration (upwards) the higher the tension".  This seems very counter-intuitive at a first glance, but it makes a lot of sense. You just have to read it the other way: if you pull harder from the cable (increase $T$), the elevator goes up quicker (increase $a$). So an increase in the acceleration of the elevator upwards needs an increase of the tension, if there are no other forces acting.

Why did I mention the "no force" part? Well, the way you asked the question could actually have another solution. You said "If I accelerate the elevator upwards", which suggests the existance of another force, $F$, independent of the tension, pushing upwards. A new free body diagram yields:
$$T+F-mg=ma$$
$$T=m(a+g)-F$$
So, see what happens here. With respect to the former case, the tension $T$ decreases if you push upward higher (assuming the acceleration $a$ is the same)

Answer (score 0):

Tension would be weight + mass * acceleration you can get the equation by considering free body diagram of elevator

Equation that comes is $T-mg = ma$

Hope it helps

Comment: But aren't g and a vectors in opposite directions?  The OP specifies an upward acceleration of the elevator...

Comment: What's OP and the equation I wrote is not a vector one I have already considered signs @DJohnM

Comment: OP = Original Post;  the question as asked...

Comment: So if we consider upward direction as positive we get  "a" positive, T positive and g negative right? @DJohnM

Comment: @DJohnM That equation is fine as is.  It's $\vec F_{net} = m \vec a$, $\vec T$ acts in the direction of $\vec a$ and $\vec g$ is the opposite direction, thus the negative sign.

Comment: Why is the tension in the same direction as the acceleration?

Answer (score 0):

For the viewpoint of an observer on the stationary ground watching the elevator move, there are two forces acting on the mass $m$: the force of gravity down $mg$ and the tension in the cable $T$ up.  The acceleration of the mass $a$, positive up, is given by $ma = T - mg$ where $a$ is also the acceleration of the elevator.  If the elevator is at rest, $a$ is zero and $T = mg$.  If the elevator is accelerating upwards, the tension increases such that $T = ma + mg$.

From the viewpoint of an observer in the moving elevator, m is stationary.  But this is a non-inertial reference frame and an additional fictitious force $-ma$ acts on the mass $m$ where $a$ is the acceleration of the elevator, positive up, relative to the outside stationary world.  In this frame since the elevator and the mass $m$ are stationary, the sum of all the forces on the mass $m$ is zero, and including the additional fictitious force $T - mg - ma = 0$, and if $a$ increases up $T$ must increase.

From either viewpoint, the tension in the cable increases if the elevator accelerates upwards, and the tension can be calculated from a force balance.